# Is "internet" a synonym of "internet-connection"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-synonyms

Well, basically: Their tag wikis say the same, I see no other application for [internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/internet) than for [internet-connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/internet-connection) and I don't see why we need to split the whole tag-system around connections into another one. And since I kinda lack the rep:

**I suggest:** Merge [internet-connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/internet-connection) into [internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/internet).

Comment: I think this would be a good idea. +1

Comment: Agree. Also note the `connection` tag, which covers internet connections already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done.

https://askubuntu.com/tags/internet/synonyms

Answer (score -1):

Ideally [internet-connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/internet-connection) would be about connecting to the Internet or troubleshooting connectivity and performance problems. The [internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/internet) tag is of course far broader.

If people don't tend to use the [internet-connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/internet-connection) tag in a way that's different from [internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/internet), we may as well merge them as proposed.

I'm not sure that's what's going on, though. Most of [internet-connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/internet-connection) questions seem to fit within the narrow scope of connectivity issues.

I recommend keeping [internet-connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/internet-connection), at least for the time being. As for the [connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/connection) tag, though, we should really get rid of that (by retagging its questions). There isn't anything practically similar about connecting to the Internet and connecting a USB mouse. The "connection" concept is too broad for a tag.

Comment: Really, I'm getting confused about how we deal with tags on AU. Two kind of people exist here, so it seems. 1) prefer to combine `simple` nouns and adjective tags, e.g. `internet` + `connection` and minimize the amount of tags. 2) prefer to have a self-descriptive and specific tag (box) for every type of question available for clean (noise free) subscriptions. Do we have a policy here?

Comment: @gertvdijk Both those approaches seem completely untenable to me, and I'm not sure it's fair to say *anyone* supports *either* of those tagging philosophies. I recommend asking about this in a new meta question.

Comment: @gertvdijk and Eliah Kagan(notified by being post owner), I feel as if we should also solicit input from other sites, as they may have a good tagging strategy we haven't even thought of.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ About tagging issues in general, I agree. About this particular question: assuming no more posts here and no change in the voting trend, we should merge [tag:internet-connection] to [tag:internet]. The proposal to do that (this question) has upvotes and this rebuttal has downvotes. It seems that those who choose to express their opinion are saying we should do the merge, so the community will on this should be done (even though my own opinion differs from it *;-)* ).